# Making a Form Fieldset text smaller after choosing an option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm new to Javascript and Jquery and i am trying to create a kind of questionnaire style page.

Essentially i want to ask a question, then once i have chosen an answer make everything in  smaller and then display the next question in normal size.

I have most of the page working in terms of showing and hiding but i cant seem to get the code to work when i try to make the initial question text smaller.

Ive read lots of tutorials and examples but none seem to work, i'd really appreciate any guidance.

Thanks in advance !

Here is my HTML

```
<form>
   <fieldset class="form1">
      <p>what problem is the customer having ?</p>
      <input type="radio" name="issue" value="o - issue1" onClick="getIssueVar()">issue1<br/>
      <input type="radio" name="issue" value="o - issue2" onClick="getIssueVar()">issue2<br/>
      <input type="radio" name="issue" value="o - issue3" onClick="getIssueVar()">issue3<br/>
      <input type="radio" name="issue" value="o - issue4" onClick="getIssueVar()">issue4<br/>
   </fieldset>
</form>
<br/>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
function getIssueVar() {
   var xissue = document.getElementById("testform");
   var issuetext = "";
   var iissue;
   for (iissue = 0; iissue < xissue.length ;iissue++) {
      if (xissue[iissue].checked) {
         issuetext=xissue[iissue].value;
         break;
      }
    }
   document.getElementById("faultissue").innerHTML = issuetext;
   $(".form2").show();
   $(".form1").css('font-size', '10px');
}
```

I have set my css:

```
.form1
{
font-size:14px;
}
```

so i was thinking i would use javascript/jquery to change the font size once ive clicked on the radio buttons.

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you put this into a jsfiddle

Comment: Do you want to show the selected answer as large text and non-selected options smaller?

Comment: I assume your `<form>` does actually have `id="testform"`, although the HTML in the question does not? Adding that, the basic making text smaller on click does actually work

Comment: sorry i'm new to this, what do you mean by a jsfiddle ?     i wasnt planning on keeping the highlighted one large but at this moment in time i will take any method i can as a building platform.

Comment: @Rhumborl   - yes i had <form id="testform" action="form_action.asp"><br/> further up, i forgot the copy and paste into here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<form>
   <fieldset class="form1">
      <p>what problem is the customer having ?</p>
      <input type="radio" name="issue" value="o - issue1" onClick="getIssueVar()" class="testform">issue1<br/>
      <input type="radio" name="issue" value="o - issue2" onClick="getIssueVar()" class="testform">issue2<br/>
      <input type="radio" name="issue" value="o - issue3" onClick="getIssueVar()" class="testform">issue3<br/>
      <input type="radio" name="issue" value="o - issue4" onClick="getIssueVar()" class="testform">issue4<br/>
   </fieldset>
</form>  

<div id="faultissue"></div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
function getIssueVar() {
    debugger
   var xissue = document.getElementsByClassName("testform");
   var issuetext = "";
   var iissue;
   for (iissue = 0; iissue < xissue.length ;iissue++) {
      if (xissue[iissue].checked) {
         issuetext=xissue[iissue].value;
         break;
      }
    }
   document.getElementById("faultissue").innerHTML = issuetext;
   $(".form2").show();
   $(".form1").css('font-size', '10px');
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mf3gcgoq/)**
From your code it seems `testform` class is missing from `radio` button tag. And an element having id `faultissue` is missing too.

Comment: Thanks loads Ozil - that works perfectly!  Thank to everyone else for responding so quickly, really appreciate it !

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jQuery solution using a [delegated on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) click approach.

```html
<form>
   <fieldset class="form1">
      <p>what problem is the customer having ?</p>
      <input type="radio" name="issue" value="o - issue1" >issue1
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="issue" value="o - issue2" >issue2
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="issue" value="o - issue3" >issue3
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="issue" value="o - issue4" >issue4
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

```css
.minimize {
    font-size: 0.5em;
}
```

```js
$('fieldset').on('click', 'input[type="radio"]', function() {
    $radio = $(this);
    $fieldset = $radio.parent();
    $fieldset.addClass('minimize');
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w4L1g2dc/

I added a class but you could set the CSS directly if you wanted.